# Find measure of $∠A$

Tags: geometry, triangles

> In an isosceles triangle $△ABC$ with $AB=AC$,  $I$ is the incentre such that $BC=AC+AI$. Find $∠A$.

My Try:

We have $BC=a$, $AB=c$, $AC=b$, and $AI=AM-IM$, where $AM$ is the altitude to base of the triangle. Now

$$AI=\frac{a}{2}\tan B-\frac{a}{2} \tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right),$$

hence using $BC=AC+AI$ we get

$$a-b=\frac{a}{2}\tan B-\frac{a}{2} \tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right).$$

How can we proceed further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $AB = AC$, then $$\sin A = \sin(π - 2B) = \sin 2B.$$ Note that $0 < B < \dfrac{π}{2}$, then$$
\tan \frac{B}{2} = \frac{\sin B}{1 + \cos B}.
$$
Thus\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{\Longleftrightarrow}} a - b = \frac{a}{2} \tan B - \frac{a}{2} \tan \frac{B}{2}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \sin 2B - \sin B = \frac{1}{2} \sin 2B \tan B - \frac{1}{2} \sin 2B \tan \frac{B}{2}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \sin B (2\cos B - 1) = \sin B \left(\sin B - \cos B \tan \frac{B}{2} \right)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow 2\cos B - 1 = \sin B - \cos B \tan \frac{B}{2}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow (2\cos B - 1)(1 + \cos B) = \sin B (1 + \cos B) - \cos B \sin B\\
&\Longleftrightarrow 2\cos^2 B + \cos B - 1 = \sin B\\
&\Longrightarrow (2\cos^2 B + \cos B - 1)^2 = 1 - \cos^2 B\\
&\Longleftrightarrow (1 + \cos B)^2 (2\cos B - 1)^2 = (1 + \cos B)(1 - \cos B)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow (1 + \cos B)(2\cos B - 1)^2 = 1 - \cos B \quad (\because 0 < B < \frac{π}{2})\\
&\Longleftrightarrow 4\cos^3 B - 2\cos B = 0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \cos B = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}. \quad (\because 0 < B < \frac{π}{2})
\end{align*}
Then$$
B = \frac{π}{4} \Longrightarrow A = \frac{π}{2}.
$$

---

*A geometric proof:*

[image]

Suppose circle $AIC$ intersect with $BC$ at point $D \neq C$. Because
$$
∠BAD = ∠BAI + ∠DAI = ∠BAI + ∠DCI = ∠BAI + ∠ABI\\
= π - ∠AIB = π - ∠AIC = π - ∠ADC = ∠BDA,
$$
then $BA = BD$. Thus,$$
AI = BC - AB = BC - BD = CD,
$$
then$$
∠ACI = ∠CID\\
\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{2} ∠BAC = ∠CAI = ∠CAD + ∠DAI = ∠ACI + ∠DCI = ∠ACB.
$$
Now it is easy to get $∠BAC = \dfrac{π}{4}$.

Comment: Well done. is it possible to do this without Trigonometry?

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma I've added a geometric proof.